# bind an ItemsTemplate datatemplate and ItemsPanelTemplate properties

Tags: binding, datatemplate, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, itemspaneltemplate

I have an `ItemsControl` with items templated as a UserControl.
My `ItemsControl.Items` `Panel` is templated as a `Canvas`.

For now, I set these my usercontrol's width and height properties manually and it looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="curveList"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SplineVMList}"
              Background="{x:Null}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="46,60,83,46"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:SplineControl Width="300" Height="300" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0" IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

What I want is to bind width and height properties of my usercontrol to those of my Canvas.
Is it just possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a relative source binding?

e.g.

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"
```